# What is the point of MultiActionController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I came across `MultiActionController` today, and I'm not sure I understand what it is used for... on the Spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html), it says

> Controller implementation that allows multiple request types to be handled by the same class. Subclasses of this class can handle several different types of request with methods of the form

On another [site](http://www.goospoos.com/2009/11/spring-multiactioncontroller-example/), they said

> It aggregates multiple request handling methods into single controller, so related functionality can be kept together easily.

I'm still not understanding how is extending `MultiActionController` better or different than the following?  Or is `MultiActionController` more a legacy from older versions of Spring?  I feel I have some basic misunderstanding...

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/SomePage.html")
    public ModelAndView epdReview(
        @RequestParam(value="sessionID", required=true) String sessionId,
        MyFormData form,
        HttpSession session,
            HttpServletRequest request){
        //....
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newData.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ValidationResponse process(Model model,
        @Valid SomeData formData, BindingResult result,
        HttpSession session) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a usage example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multiactioncontroller-example/) which implements Create, Read, Update and Delete methods.  The actions are related because they all operate on the Customer object.

Comment: Oh I see, it looks like `MultiActionController` is an older usage... I found another [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multiactioncontroller-annotation-example/) from the page you gave that says `@RequestMapping` is the annotation based `MultiActionController`

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  ASP.NET MVC uses attributes similar to this, and has never had a Multi-Action Controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is from the Spring 2.0 MVC API, as is anything that implements the old [Controller Interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html).  I can't find anything around the web from a Spring Developer regarding why this one was not deprecated when all of its cousins were.

I could offer 100% pure speculation that it could be because people could have totally valid custom-implementations of the [MethodNameResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MethodNameResolver.html) that are impossible to replace with the behaviour of DefaultAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.  Therefore annotation based config does not provide a 100% alternative to every legitimate use of this class.

Comment: Thanks Affe, your comment helps clear up a confusion I had after reading on a diff older thread that "all" the controllers were deprecated (which didn't make sense, so now I at least know that much).

Comment: BaseCommandController and "down" are all deprecated, which covers almost everything, but as we see, not quite!  Perhaps they also just wanted to leave some assurance for people who built their own ground-up implementations of the Controller Interface that the dispatcher servlet's basic ability to hand off requests to their code was not in danger of being removed.

Comment: The reason this is not deprecated is because annotations create a binding of I/O to the controller wherein the I/O data cannot be shared with architectural components creating an architectural cross cutting concern in considerations with API's. Classes like this allow for the communication to be abstracted so the controller is a single concern and secondary concerns can be separated and shared with architectural components.

Answer (score 1):

Spring offers a multi-action controller with which multiple actions can be aggregated into one controller, grouping functionality together. The multi-action controller is capable of mapping requests to method names and then invoking the right method name. Using the multi-action controller is especially handy when you have a lot of common functionality in one controller, but want to have multiple entry points to the controller

Answer (score 0):

The hole point of using Annotated Controllers - like your later example- is support for request handling without depending on inheritance or framework specific classes (like four first example). In [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html) you can find this:

> Spring 2.5 introduces an annotation-based programming model for MVC
>   controllers, using annotations such as @RequestMapping, @RequestParam,
>   @ModelAttribute, etc. This annotation support is available for both
>   Servlet MVC and Portlet MVC. Controllers implemented in this style do
>   not have to extend specific base classes or implement specific
>   interfaces.

So, if you're already using Annotated Controllers there's no point in extending Spring built-in Controllers like `MultiActionController`.

Comment: Thanks Carlos.  I started reading/doing Spring in version 3, so I often find myself still confused over why something is done one way or another. Feeling like I need to learn both Spring 2.5 and Spring 3 to fully learn the Spring framework

Answer (score 0):

Spring MultiActionController is used to map similar actions to single controller. So If you use MultiActionController class, you do not need to create new controller class for each action.

For example: When we login to internet banking, there is an option to add and delete payee. So we can use single PayeeController to perform similar actions such as add and delete.

Answer (score -1):

Quoted from [mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multiactioncontroller-example/):

In Spring MVC application, MultiActionController is used to group related actions into a single controller, the method handler have to follow below signature :

```
public (ModelAndView | Map | String | void) actionName(
    HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse [,HttpSession] [,CommandObject]);
```

example

```
package com.vitthal.common.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;

public class CustomerController extends MultiActionController{

    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","add() method");

    }

    public ModelAndView delete(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","delete() method");

    }

    public ModelAndView update(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","update() method");

    }

    public ModelAndView list(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("CustomerPage", "msg","list() method");

    }

}
```

With ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping configured.

```
<beans ...>

 <bean 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

  <bean class="com.mkyong.common.controller.CustomerController" />

</beans>
```

Mapping Examples
Now, the requested URL will map to the method name in the following patterns :

```
CustomerController –> /customer/*
/customer/add.htm –> add()
/customer/delete.htm –> delete()
/customer/update.htm –> update()
/customer/list.htm –> list()
```

InternalPathMethodNameResolver
The InternalPathMethodNameResolver is the default MultiActionController implementation to map URL to method name. But, you are still allow to add prefix or suffix to the method name :

```
<beans ...>
 <bean 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

  <bean class="com.vitthal.common.controller.CustomerController">
     <property name="methodNameResolver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.InternalPathMethodNameResolver">
       <property name="prefix" value="test" />
       <property name="suffix" value="Customer" />
    </bean>
     </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Now, the URL will map to the method name in the following pattern :

```
CustomerController –> /customer/*
/customer/add.htm –> testaddCustomer()
/customer/delete.htm –> testdeleteCustomer()
/customer/update.htm –> testupdateCustomer()
/customer/list.htm –> testlistCustomer()
```

Note
With annotation, the MultiActionController is more easy to configure

Comment: I see lots of examples on the internet, and now you've provided another one here.  What I'm not clear on (and what the OP is not clear on) is why wouldn't you use an ordinary Controller for this?

Comment: @Vitthal Thanks, I can read the example on the mkyong site myself ;)

Comment: Generally we have mapping in xml file for dispatcher servlet to decide which controller to use as per URL mapping but if we have to take decision on basis of request parameters then MultiActionController can be used.

Spring offers a multi-action controller with which multiple actions can be aggregated into one controller, grouping functionality together. The multi-action controller is capable of mapping requests to method names and then invoking the right method name.

Comment: Using the multi-action controller is especially handy when you have a lot of common functionality in one controller, but want to have multiple entry points to the controller.

Comment: And want to seriously confuse the interns... :)